# How to check if value is in range of cells?

Tags: google-sheets

In a Google Sheets spreadsheet, I want to check if the value of a cell exists in a range of cells. How can I do this?

Just like you would be able to do "if value in list_of_values" in Python for example.

Comment: Were you able to apply my solutions?

Comment: If booleans are the desired output, a shorter variation of the `MATCH` answer [from below](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/73926) can be: `=NOT(ISNA(MATCH(A1; B1:B10; 0)))`.

Answer (score 124):

You could use COUNTIF.

For example:

```
=COUNTIF(G:G,6) > 0
```

if you want to find the number `6` in the range G:G, and/or

```
=COUNTIF(A1:B7,"d") > 0
```

if you want to find `d` in the first seven rows of the first two columns.

COUNTIF will return the number of instances in its given range that are equal to its given value. It can also do a bit more complex conditioning (e.g all values higher than 6, or containing the letter A); see the [docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en) for more info.

Comment: @transang as author (I believe you) wrote in the linked article: "never use countif when the criterion parameter (the second parameter) is dynamic". Emphasis on dynamic. The OP asks for a static one.

Comment: @meridius Yes. I am the author of the linked article. The OP does not mention whether **the value** is static or dynamic. `I want to check if **the value** of a cell exists in a range of cells`

Comment: @transang sorry, I got what OP asked and what pnuts suggested mixed up. This answer is for static case, in a dynamic one you're of course right.

Comment: =COUNTIF(H85:H90; "Pending")
Some locales require the use of a semi-colon as an argument separator. 
https://support.google.com/docs/thread/18510720?hl=en

Comment: @transang still, your title says you should never use it, which is in direct contradiction with what you wrote in the body. Further, you have made a circular reference and presented it as an existing rule instead of something you came up with in response to this very answer. The mods should remove that link.

Answer (score 49):

You could try `MATCH`:

```
A1     = [Value you are trying to find]
B1:B10 = [Range you are searching in]

=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1;B1:B10;0));"Not found";"Found")
```

You can replace the `A1` with formulas that return a value to search for. The `0` ensures actual search, not presupposing an ordered search range.

Ref: [Documentation for MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en)

Comment: The `0` is super helpful, much easier than having to worry about how the second sheet is sorted.

Answer (score 4):

User can do that in different ways (any of the following may apply):

`=IFERROR(IF(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B,B2:B="text"))="text";"Found";"Not Found");"Not Found")`

`=IFERROR(IF(COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(range="text"),TRUE)>0;"Found";"Not Found");"Not Found")`

`=IFERROR(IF(COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(FIND("text", FILTER(range,range<>""))),">"&0)>0;"Found";"Not Found");"Not Found")`

Comment: Thanks. How can I do something similar without exact match but rather by checking if "text" is contained as part of a string in any of the cells of the B2:B range?

Answer (score -2):

Use GoogleSpreadsheet and there

```
=vlookup(C2;A2:B4;2;false)
```

and then connect document via API.

Comment: Can anyone explain why this is "-3" ?

Comment: @meeDamian because if the value is not found it will raise an error