# Formula works in cells but not in conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

So, I have a Gantt chart style diary.  I want to apply conditional formatting to any column whose date (in row 2), is a public holiday.  There is a sheet called 'Public Holidays', that has the dates of all public holidays in column A.

I found a relevant formula to try from Peter Smulders answer to this topic: [How to check if value is in range of cells?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/42340/how-to-check-if-value-is-in-range-of-cells)

Here's my version:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(B$2:RV$2, 'Public Holidays'!$A:$A,0)))
```

Nothing happens.  It doesn't activate on any cells or columns whether public holidays or not.  Weirdly though, if I paste that formula into a bunch of cells, it returns correctly, ie any cell in a column whose date in row 2 is a public holiday returns `TRUE` and any cell in a column whose date is not a public holiday returns `FALSE`.

I don't understand why it works as a cell formula but not as a conditional formatting formula.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's a copy of my sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sYI2oDyDR5p5oIJvE_AKIUm_PMReL4nGfXlMU5YvRxI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy of your sheet pls

Comment: edited original post to include link to shared copy of sheet.

Comment: what range you want to color ? `B3:NC` or `B:NC` ?

Comment: ```B3:NC``` please

Comment: you need `indirect` if you want to reference other sheets in conditional formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH($B$2:$NC$2, INDIRECT("'Public Holidays'!$A:$A"), 0)))
```

[image: 0]